# Refer to a row in different sheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I'm trying to make a table from excel sheet where table elements will be referred to a particular row.

```
for example

  This is my row 4 data and I'm trying to create table using header and this 4 row. 
  
       4/27/2021    78  3   3   0   0

  so, when next time when I insert data row 4, the table should be updated to the inserted data,
  but my data is now referring to row 5.
```

I tried:

```
=Sheet1!A$4 
=Sheet1!$A$4 
=Sheet1!A4

I tied all 3 formula to refer to my sheet 1 excel, but next time when I'm inserting data in row 4, table is referring to row 5.How can I do this ?
```

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,4)`

Comment: You can also use `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A4")`

Comment: Though `INDIRECT` is volatile and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!A1;3;)`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would advise against adding new rows on top of existing datasets (rather add them below the existing data and use a formula to retrieve the last entry).

In case you want to proceed with your current approach, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1335789/stop-excel-formula-from-changing-when-inserting-deleting-rows) is a good explanation of why this is happening and what you would need to do to achieve your desired outcome.